# casting between sibling classes, AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, casting, siblings

I have two classes, `derivedClassA` and `derivedClassB` which both extend `parentClass`
I'm declaring `var o:parentClass` and then, depending on what's going on, I want to cast `o` as either being of type `derivedClassA` or `derivedClassB`.

Essentially, this:

```
var o:parentClass  

...  

if(shouldUseA)  
    o = new derivedClassA();  
else  
    o = new derivedClassB();  
o.doSomething();
```

But it's not working, I'm getting all sorts of errors.  Isn't this how class inheritance works?  I feel like I'm missing something really fundamental, but I can't figure out what.  Am I supposed to be using interfaces instead?  Is there another way of doing what I want?

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:
- `doSomething()` is defined in `parentClass` as public, and in the derived classes as `override public function doSomething()`
- errors I'm getting are "Call to a possibly undefined method doSomething through a reference with static type parentClass." and "Implicit coercion of a value of type derviedClassA to an unrelated type parentClass"

Comment: what errors are you getting?  is doSomething defined in parentClass or just the child classes?

Comment: Your question is different than your example.  In your question you're saying that you're declaring `var o:classA` and trying to cast it to `classB` which won't work.  You should, however, be able to do what the example says, which is declaring `var o:parentClass` and then assigning it a value of one of its child classes.

Which are you trying to do and what errors are you getting?

Also, as asked above: is doSomething defined on the parent class?  If not, you'll need to cast beforehand (ie: classA(o).doSomething();)

Comment: And, standards-wise you should use CapitalizedNamesForClasses. Shouldn't be affecting your results, but just so that you know those names are non-conventional.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Austin, I've fixed the mistake; the example is correct.  `doSomething()` is defined in `parentClass`
as public, and in the derived classes as `override public function doSomething()`
The errors I'm getting are 
"Call to a possibly undefined method doSomething through a reference with static type parentClass."  
and
"Implicit coercion of a value of type derviedClassA to an unrelated type parentClass"

Comment: This shouldn't happen - are you sure that `DerviedClassA extends ParentClass` and that you didn't forget to declare `doSomething` in `ParentClass`?

Comment: The two errors you are getting suggest that there is more than just a missing "extends", that would explain the unrelated type error, but not the fact that you can't even call the parent class doSomething. Sounds to me like your class path is not set up right, such that the definition of your "parentClass" is not being found at compile time. Files named to match the classes?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before: throw error in what is meant to be a virtual function in the base class, to obviously point out when mistakenly calling it. I do this when I make abstract base classes.

**Main.as** (Document Class)

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var superClassRef:SuperClass;
        private var idLikeToBuyAnA:Boolean = true;

        public function Main()
        {
            trace("Main()");
            if (idLikeToBuyAnA)
            {
                superClassRef = new DerivedClassA();
            }
            else
            {
                superClassRef = new DerivedClassB();
            }

            superClassRef.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

**SuperClass.as**

```
package
{
    public class SuperClass
    {
        public function SuperClass()
        {
        }

        public function doSomething():void
        {
            throw new Error("Override me, I wish I were virtual!");
        }
    }
}
```

**DerivedClassA.as**

```
package
{
    public class DerivedClassA extends SuperClass
    {
        public function DerivedClassA()
        {
        }

        override public function doSomething():void
        {
            trace("I'm and A!");
        }
    }
}
```

**DerivedClassB.as**

```
package
{
    public class DerivedClassB extends SuperClass
    {
        public function DerivedClassB()
        {
        }

        override public function doSomething():void
        {
            trace("I'm a B!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a Interface to be able to do what you are asking for. This you you don't have to cast the variable, and it will give you access to your doSomething function.
Here is a small example using your your structure:
Note that all the classes are in the same root package, hence there is no import statements.

**MainApp.as** (this is the default application)

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class MainApp extends Sprite 
    {
        private var parentClass : IParent;
        private var doA : Boolean = false;

        public function MainApp()
        {

            if (doA)
            parentClass = new DerivedClassA();
            else
            parentClass = new DerivedClassB();

            parentClass.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

**Parent.as**

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Parent extends Sprite
    {
        public function Parent()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**DerivedClassA.as**

```
package  
{
    public class DerivedClassA extends Parent implements IParent
    {
        public function DerivedClassA()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function doSomething() : void 
        {
            trace (this + " done something");
        }
    }
}
```

**DerivedClassB.as**

```
package  
{
    public class DerivedClassB extends Parent implements IParent
    {
        public function DerivedClassB()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function doSomething() : void 
        {
            trace (this + " done something");
        }
    }
}
```

**IParent.as**

```
package  
{
    public interface IParent 
    {
        function doSomething():void;
    }
}
```

As you can, see using a Interface, you call the function doSomething without the casting.
There is no problem about casting variables, but this can give you a more structured code, and it will assure you have the doSomething method in the classes that implement the interface.
Hope it helps...
G luck

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution as-is.  Anything typed as the interface wouldn't be able to access the other properties of the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

The specific answer to the question you asked is this:

```
o["doSomething"]();
```

However, I can't recommend that you do that.  I think the real issue is that your parent class should define doSomething(), then the derived classes should override the function.